Using Googlesheets query with multiple selections from a drop-down list
I want to query all data from another tab if the column matches the names selected in the drop-down validation. Please see the images below which will help!
Image 1: Contains the query and the drop-down cell
Image 2: Shows how the selected names from the drop-down are formatted.

Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange.
See How do I ask a good question?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to stackoverflow! Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

To get rows in 'Sheet37' where column E matches the value in cell B4, use filter() with search(), like this:
=filter(Sheet37!B7:AG, search(Sheet37!E7:E, B4))

See filter() and search().
